# What is meant by $\int\chi_A$ as the definition of the Jordan measure of $A$, where $\chi_A$ is the indicator function of $A$?

Tags: measure-theory

In order to better understand the underpinnings of calculus, I am trying to study various concepts of measures and measure theory, beginning with the Jordan measure.

[This lecture](http://math.uchicago.edu/~j.e.hickman/162%20Lecture%20notes/Lecture%2023%20and%2024.pdf) by Jonathan Hickman of the University of Chicago asserts exactly the following:

> **Definition.** Given a set $A\subseteq\Bbb R$ we let $\chi_A:\Bbb{R}\to\{0,1\}$ be the characteristic or indicator function of $A$, defined by $$\chi_A(x):= \begin{cases} 1 & \text{if $x\in A$} \\ 0 & \text{otherwise} \\ \end{cases}$$
>
> **Definition.** We will say a set $A\subseteq\Bbb{R}$ is *Jordan measurable* if $\chi_A$ [is] Riemann integrable. In this case we can associate a notion of size $\mu(A)$ to $A$ given by $$\mu(A):=\int\chi_A$$
>
> Here $\mu(A)$ is called the *Jordan measure* of $A$.

Having only one year of calculus under my belt, I am not at all accustomed to integrating without respect to a variable except when integrating differential forms.

This is how I understand Riemann integration:

> [image: Riemann integral]
>
> $$\begin{align}
> \int_a^b f(x) \, dx &= \lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{i=1}^{n}h \cdot w \\
> &= \lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{i=1}^{n} f\!\left(a+iw\right) \cdot \frac{b-a}{n} \\
> &= \lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{i=1}^{n} f\!\left(a+i\frac{b-a}{n}\right) \cdot \frac{b-a}{n} \\
> \end{align}$$

So, for example, take the set $B$ to be the closed interval $[2,3]$. Then is the following implied?

$$\begin{align}
\int\chi_B &= \lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{i=1}^{n}h \\
&= \lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{i=1}^{n}\chi_B\!\left(2+\frac{i}{n}\right) \\
\end{align}$$

Surely this cannot be right; this [Desmos](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/uqslde9v1l) clearly suggests that the sequence of partial sums of $\{\chi_B(2+i/x)\}$ for natural values of $i$ less than or equal to natural values of $x$ diverges as $x\to\infty$. (Hopefully I phrased that sentence correctly.)

Could anyone shed some light on this topic?

<sub>*If you find additional tags are appropriate, please suggest an edit to include them or indicate so in the comments.*</sub>

Comment: All Riemann sums are finite sums and we take the lower sum and upper sum over possible midpoints to check for integrability (these sums are the same for characteristic functions). We are not taking limits of infinite sums liek $\frac{1}{n}$ and also only within a closed interval.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For $B = [2,3]$, the characteristic function is just the function $1$ for $x \in [2,3]$ and $0$ for $x \notin [2,3]$, whose graph is just interval of length $1$ at height $1$ between $2$ and $3$. The Riemann integral is simply the limit of the sum of areas of rectangles underneath the graph, so just the area underneath the graph (to the $x$-axis) and this is a rectangle of area $1\cdot(3-2) = 1$. So that is the Jordan measure of $[2,3]$. In general we'll get $\mu([a,b]) = b-a$.

Comment: Could you address the notation $\int\chi_A$ as opposed to $\int\chi_A\,dx$?

Comment: @ChaseRyanTaylor that’s just a shorthand for it.

Comment: Very weird… ${}{}{}{}{}{}{}$

Comment: @ChaseRyanTaylor the boundaries are also such that $A$ lies between them.

Comment: The boundaries of $A$?

Comment: @ChaseRyanTaylor a Riemann integral always goes from some $a$ to $b$. I call these the boundaries.